# Hotels data for analytics

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, database

I'd like to ask where can I get hotels data such as addresses, images, descriptions, coordinates, facilities, reviews? I've read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185961/travel-hotel-apis), but couldn't find any appropriate ways for today. Note: we're planning to use data only for analytics and building our own recomendation system, so our customers won't have access to this data, therefore we don't match most of the requirements for affiliate programs.

Any suggestions on some API or other web resources to get this data?

Answer (score 1):

[Expedia's Hotel Data hosted by Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/expedia-personalized-sort/data): Here you find the ID of the hotel (arbitrary) and country in which the hotel is located, mean price per night, number of searches on Expedia for a given hotel, mean customer review score

US public data also has some [datasets located geographically](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=hotel). Information varies and it requires some processing.

[data.world has also hotels datasets](https://data.world/datasets/hotel) stored on github or other websites. There are some datasets with very permissive licenses.

Community dataset hosted on Kaggle called: [515K Hotel Reviews Data in Europe](https://www.kaggle.com/jiashenliu/515k-hotel-reviews-data-in-europe) not a lot to analyze other than reviews. Useful for NLP related models.

[Tourpedia dataset](http://tour-pedia.org/about/datasets.html): Liberal license and also includes other points of interests like Restaurants, attractions, etc.